# Getting point as 5 instead of 10 for each upvote in my answer - Why?

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, up-votes

Recently I have [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988335/rubyunion-of-two-regular-expressions/25988382#25988382) of one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988335/rubyunion-of-two-regular-expressions).

I found some strange points for each upvotes. I am getting `5` instead of `10` for each vote. Why so?

> [image]

Comment: Any chance you are hitting the daily rep-cap?

Comment: No.. I didn't hit anywhere..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting +10 for each of the 3 upvotes to that answer.

I think the confusion is because someone unaccepted a previous answer of yours recently. Which caused a -15. So you had +15 sum after +30 -15 = 15

[image]

Comment: Any  chance the confusion is due to him hitting the daily rep-cap?

Comment: Yes.. That's the reason.. :-) I just noticed.. It was not there.

Comment: Nice detective work!

Comment: Yes.. Indeed.. detective.. :-)